# Autocomplete in Ionic input

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I want to know if it's possible to have autocomplete on an ionic input. 
I have another question : is it possible to add bootstrap to Ionic application (with bootstrap I can use [ngbTypeahead] for the same purpose)
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this repo as an example [for ionic v2](https://github.com/kadoshms/ionic2-autocomplete)

and write your own autocomplete using a `*ngFor`

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestions" (click)="addSuggestion(suggestion)">
        {{suggestion}}
    </ion-item>
```

Or if you use Ionic 4 use this , great documentation and usage: [Ionic v4](https://github.com/jrquick17/ionic4-auto-complete)